# Revising answers to Game History questions

Tags: discussion

I am not sure how to put this into the form of a question or it needs to be. What I want to do is make folks aware of Jon Petersons [Playing at the World](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0615642047) a book about the history of roleplaying games and wargaming.

What sets this book off from previous efforts at roleplaying history is that Peterson has documented nearly every section of the book. This is possible due to the rise of the roleplaying collector market in the past decade and Peterson has or gained access to a huge variety of documents spanning the dawn of wargames to the mid 70s the cut off time of the book. The book is extensively footnoted point out the sources of specific paragraphs.

People should keep this source in mind when answering History of Gaming questions like the one on the origin of experience points.

Addition:
I was a little confused at Mxyzplk answer and looking over my question I think why.

I am NOT proposing to post anything on the main rpg.stackexchange.com site. I was just wondering how to post the info here on meta as I think mentioning Playing at the World is a meta issue not something for the main site. I do appreciate the info on the community ads.

Answer (score 2):

Well, this falls into the category of "I kinda want to pimp something, I know that's spam but it's something really useful. How does that work on a SE?"

First, you know you have to be careful not to overstep.  If the book contains info that informs a good answer to a question, great, answer the question and refer to the book as a reference.

Second, "but I want to pimp it more."  Mention it in chat.  Propose a community promotion ad (http://meta.rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/1497/community-promotion-ads-2012). Put it in your user profile.  But that's about it.  The rules apply evenly to a super cool useful thing you like as they do to a random game-spammer, so we can't say "Well it's Batty, he can make some fake questions that are really ads," obviously.  But leverage the community - answers, community ads, etc. are things that get voted up or down by the community, so if you're doing it right then the pimping will happen. Do it obnoxiously, and you'll get pimp slapped.

Comment: So many uses of pimp.

Comment: Added pimp slap just for you.

Comment: Pimping aside, Playing at the World is an important work in regards to gaming history. And since one of the goals of a Stack Exchange site is to provide high quality answers people here need to be aware of it. Especially consider there been several gaming history questions asked.

Comment: It sounds like a useful reference for citing statements made in answers to history questions. Use it like that, and it should be fine. Aside, I would totally vote up a community ad for the book.

Comment: Yeah, I appreciate "people here should be aware of it."  And I might even agree (though lots of people think that about a lot of things) - but pimp it within site boundaries.  Blog the shit out of it on your own time though!  I'll link it from Geek Related.